# Pen Drive Not opening

Tags: windows-xp

Yesterday when I was working on a Word file located on my pen drive, my computer suddenly shut down and after some time when it restarted I was not in a position to open my pen drive. On double click/open option/explore option on message box is appearing with message "you need to format this disk. do you want to format it ?"
Please advise me what to do. Is it possible to recover all data to open the drive after formatting?

Comment: Did you try the drive with a linux machine?

Answer (score 2):

No, please do not format it in any event, otherwise your data will be certainly deleted.

There may be data loss in the middle of writing to the USB, which possibly damaged the File Allocation Table (FAT).

You can try to search for USB / SD Card recovery software that can read every sector of your pen drive which may have a chance to recover your files.